# Rapache on debian wheezy doesn't work with R 3.1.2

Tags: php, r, debian, rapache

its been a long time that I'm trying to install rapache on debian. I did follow this tutorial : http://blog.binfalse.de/2011/05/28/r-for-the-web/ and I made it work but with a old R (1.2.5) and I did repeat the installation exactly the same way but with R (3.1.2) and I have "Internal Server Error" when I type "localhost/R/myfile.R". But, when I type "localhost/RApacheInfo", it works !! This is my file "r.conf"

```
<Location /RApacheInfo>
SetHandler r-info
</Location>
<Location /R>
SetHandler r-script
RHandler sys.source
</Location>
```

Here is my error.log apache file. I took only the end of it because its is too long :

```
      unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/library/stats/libs/stats.so':
  libRlapack.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
During startup - Warning message:
package 'stats' in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/library/stats/libs/stats.so':
  libRlapack.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
During startup - Warning message:
package 'stats' in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/library/stats/libs/stats.so':
  libRlapack.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
During startup - Warning message:
package 'stats' in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/library/stats/libs/stats.so':
  libRlapack.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
During startup - Warning message:
package 'stats' in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/library/stats/libs/stats.so':
  libRlapack.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
During startup - Warning message:
package 'stats' in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
[Tue Dec 15 18:40:12 2015] [error] [client ::1] rApache Notice!
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "rnorm"
Traceback:
3: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
2: eval(exprs[i], envir)
1: sys.source(file = "/var/www/R/test.R", envir = .rAenv)
[Tue Dec 15 18:40:14 2015] [error] [client ::1] rApache Notice!
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "rnorm"
Traceback:
3: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
2: eval(exprs[i], envir)
1: sys.source(file = "/var/www/R/test.R", envir = .rAenv)
[Tue Dec 15 18:40:15 2015] [error] [client ::1] rApache Notice!
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "rnorm"
Traceback:
3: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
2: eval(exprs[i], envir)
1: sys.source(file = "/var/www/R/test.R", envir = .rAenv)
```

And when I'm trying to put some php/html code, it does work as long as its not in localhost/R. Every code I put here give me this "Internal Server Error". I've tried already to install it from 0 twice and same result. Hope you can help me :)

Comment: Any info in apache error log ? My crystal is in maintenance I can't guess what your server tells you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finnaly found how to make it work !!
You can find it on this post :
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rapache/axLb5PsS9LY
So happy :)
Resolved